# How to I set the cursor to the Drag Copy/Move cursors in Win32?

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop, cursors

It doesn't seem to be one of the standard cursors (like IDC_ARROW), so how can I load this?

Comment: Could you elaborate that? I have no idea which cursor you're thinking about.

Comment: I mean the Drag-Copy (which has the little plus in the corner on XP for example), and the Drag-Move.  I'm doing some d&d within my app, and it would be nice to have the same cursors to afford the same kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a custom cursor as a resource to your application, get the resource handle, and then use SetCursor(...)

The drag/copy/move cursors aren't part of the standard library - your application will need it's own.  The standard cursors are all listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648391(VS.85).aspx

That being said, IDC_HAND does exist on newer operating systems, which may be what you are looking for...

Comment: Darn, we're deploying for multiple windows platforms including Vista/XP, so I guess we would have to bundle icons for each?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You can use teh same icons on XP + Vista.  Vista does add the ability to have higher quality icons, though, so if you want them to look as nice as the other icons on vista, you'll need multiple resources.

Comment: Sorry, I meant cursor, not icon -- since vista/xp seems to have different plus/move cursors.  Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah - same issue, though.  You'd just need to load multiple icons into your resource file, and pick the one you want.